# Remove space from string and join using comma

Tags: javascript

I am using this javascript to split new line to comma. Now on top of this I need to truncate spaces between each values. Below is my javascript.

```
<script>
function convert() {
var data = document.getElementById("get").value;
var lines = data.split('\r\n');
document.getElementById("display").value = lines.join(',');
}
</script>
```

Comment: This question really isn't that bad people. [should SO be awarding As for effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)

Comment: Thanks Liam. Maybe someone thinks its a piece of cake and not me as I'm a starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop though the lines and trim each line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
```

Inserted in your code:

```
<script>
function convert() {
var data = document.getElementById("get").value;
var lines = data.split('\r\n');
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
document.getElementById("display").value = lines.join(',');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.replace` would be more efficient. You can even handle the three different newline standards:

```
document.getElementById('display').value =
       document.getElementById('get').value.replace(/ *(?=[\r\n])\r?\n? */g,",");
```

You can also account for empty lines, by tacking on `.replace(/,,+/g,',')` to collapse sequences of two or more commas.

Comment: This won't trim the starting and trailing spaces in the value.

Comment: True. But again, you can just add `.replace(/^,+|,+$/g,'')` to fix that. That's the beauty of this, you can just keep chaining stuff ^_^

Comment: OK but why so complicated than? Maybe simply with `/ *\r?\n */g`?

Comment: Old Macs use just `\r` alone for newlines. `(?=[\r\n])\r?\n?` is for the sake of completeness and maximum compatibility. It doesn't hurt ;)

Comment: Really? That's odd! Didn't know about it... Let it be than :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Trim function to remove spaces

```
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  lines[i] = lines[i].trim();
   }
```

Comment: The `trim` method is a method on a string, not an array. Also, it only exist in newer browsers, e.g. IE 9+.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
<script>
function convert() {
    var data = document.getElementById("get").value;
    var lines = data.split('\r\n');
    var newLines = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i].replace(/\s+$/, '');
        if (line.length > 0) {
            newLines.push(line);
        }
    }
    if (newLines.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("display").value = newLines.join(',');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: trim function removes leading/trailing spaces on specified string. I've replaced with a regex (same thing). see updated post.

Comment: `String.trim()`, maybe, but `trim()` alone doesn't exist :p Also, what you have is more like `rtrim()`.

Answer (score -1):

use below

```
<script>
function convert() {
    var data = document.getElementById("get").value;
    var lines = data.split('\r\n');
    var lines = lines.trim();
    document.getElementById("display").value = lines.join(',');
}
</script>
```

Comment: [Please note that `.trim()` only is available in Firefox 3.5+, Chrome, IE9+, Opera 10.5+ and Sarafi 5+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: There are the following problems in your answer: 1. You can't apply `.trim()` method for arrays. 2. `.trim()` is not supported by old browsers.

Comment: ok got it. so what will be the solution? instead of the above answer I don't know any solution. So You guys please help OP for his question.

Comment: I can't see `linen` declared anywhere... and `lines` doesn't have a `trim` method